# Plotting dataframe in different locales

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem that I could not figure out.
I have a DataFrame (df) that looks like the attached picture[image]

The contents of this DataFrame are converted to datetime and used for plotting in Power BI based on what I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76347563/how-to-format-datetimes-in-power-bi-for-a-matplotlib-visualization) with the following code which you can find in the link

```html
df = df.apply(lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'), axis=0)
```

my problem is that when I am working with a computer that has United state settings then the below line works perfectly

```html
df.plot(x='Scale',ax=ax, rot=0,linewidth=.5, marker='o')
```

but when I write the same code on a German computer then suddenly this stops working and I get a strange plot so I would be grateful if you tell me what's wrong and how can I make it work?

I suspect the naT is causing problems.

Comment: Could you share a plot and also some sample rows of your current output with from the German computer please?

Comment: Decimal separators are different in different countries. Additionally, you may be running into a date issue. German dates are formatted DD-MM-YY. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49204/in-germany-commas-are-used-as-decimal-separators-in-numbers-so-what-character